# Generating Static Site with Components and Tailwind

Tags: html, vite

I'm looking for a solution in a non fully explored word like nodejs.

I wanted to use some static pages for my mcu esp32 which have 1mb of space.

At the moment I'm using Vite, with tailwind 3 and it work well, but I have some "problems"

1. For all files vite is going to generate, are generating empty js files cause I don't use and I have to delete all call in the header ("minor problem")
2. I don't understand or maybe Vite don't have, the use of components, so I have to copy and paste nav bar every time to 4 different pages
3. Page generation don't minify the html pages, there's a way to force it?

Is there another way to solve these "problems"?